# Checking if $timeout is pending

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I've this $timeout set inside my script and its code was wrote like this:

```
        timeout = $timeout(function () {
                            
            scope.eventHandler.apply(this, arguments);                                              
            
        }, scope.ngDebounceOptions.time)
        timeout.then(function(){},function(){},function(){})
```

After setting the var timeout I got this result when I fire JSON.stringify(timeout):

```
{"$$state":{"status":0,"pending":[[{"promise":{"$$state":{"status":0}}},null,null,null]]},"$$timeoutId":210}
```

And I'got this result when when I fire JSON.stringify(timeout) after timeout time elapse:

```
{"$$state":{"status":1,"processScheduled":false},"$$timeoutId":86}
```

My question is: how to check if `timeoout` has status `0` or `1`?

Comment: How about the naive approach of `timeout['$$state'].status`?

Comment: @derpirscher I got this error while trying to make a condition: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$$state')"

Comment: This means your `timeout` variable is `undefined` in that moment ...